# Where to get username and password for mysql after installing npm install mysql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

Modifying to actual requirement.

I have html file called temp.html
I want to display select query result in that html page.
This is my select query.

```
    SELECT cs_name FROM course_master where cs_id = 4
```

This query will return following result.

```
[ { cs_name: 'JAVA programming' } ]
```

I want to display this result in html page.
Basically I want to use the **"GET"** request and response using node js.
This is my node js file structure.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : '127.0.0.1',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'eduportal'
});
connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT cs_name FROM course_master where cs_id = 4', function(err, rows, fields) {
if (!err)
console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
else
console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});
connection.end();
```

This is my HTML file.

```
<!doctype html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>        
</head>
<body>
    <div id="course_name">          
        Course Name:<input type="text" id="cname">                
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display course name in text box which I defined in HTML file.

Can anyone help to bind this text box with mysql using node js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure what is the meaning of this.

It means that the `mysql` nodes module is installed with required dependencies.

> where to see Username and password for database connection

This is just a driver. You must install MySql in your desktop/server. There you may need to setup username and password for the database.

> where to create the my database after installation of mysql.

Again, its just a driver. You need to create them in your MySQL application in your server/desktop.

For more reference, **[refer the npm module doc](http://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)**

Once you create the database in your desktop/server, use the module to establish the connection.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret'
});
```

Comment: I have already installed xampp server. I am using mysql for my application using xampp. So my question is which username and password I need to mention while creating connection ? Is that same username and password which I am using for mysql ?

Comment: Great. In your mysql, create a database and create a user and assign that user to localhost. You can use that credential to establish the connection. Yes, its same username and password you use for mysql